# Ckeditor 4 horizontal stretching

Tags: ckeditor

Using [Ckeditor 4](http://ckeditor.com/) is there a way to set the width of the editor for initial load but still allow it to be stretched horizontally?

The little nub in the bottom right corner only seems to allow vertical stretching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because resize plugin by default allows resizing only vertically.

There's however a [config.resize_dir](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-resize_dir) option, which you have to set to `'both'`. Check also other options like [resize_maxWidth](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-resize_maxWidth) which may be useful for you.